# Reporting percentages in preference type survey questions

Tags: survey, reporting

I came a cross some survey results that show user preferences, asked in the form of the most and least preferred choices. The result reported was something like "x % of people chose option A as their most preferred" and "y % of people chose option B as their least preferred". It seems to me that there is some dependency between what someone would prefer to what someone would least prefer, so instead they should show the breakdown of least preferred options for people who chose option A as their most preferred option (and vice versa). I want to ask whether presenting the percentages as a total only is misleading.